# Negative bound in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm making a program where I calculate a random number using a function named `generarAleatorio`.

```
public static int generarAleatorio(int l){
        java.util.Random X = new java.util.Random();
        return X.nextInt(l) ;
    }
```

Then, I use that number to locate a value inside an array using the length of the array as the parameter for the `generarAleatorio` parameter

```
public static String generarFecha(){

int[] dias={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

int[] mes={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

return String.format("%d-%d",dias[generarAleatorio(dias.length)],
                             mes[generarAleatorio(generarAleatorio(mes.length))]);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes an Exception is showed that looks like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at generadorregistros.GeneradorRegistros.generarAleatorio(GeneradorRegistros.java:70)
    at generadorregistros.GeneradorRegistros.generarFecha(GeneradorRegistros.java:108)
    at generadorregistros.GeneradorRegistros.main(GeneradorRegistros.java:48)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It tells me that the Bound im sending its not positive, but as far as I know, the length of the Array is always the same and also positive.

What's the cause of this? Is the length of the array not always positive?

Comment: Zero is not a positive number (it isn't negative either) and you're passing the result of the first call to nextInt, which may be zero, to the next call of nextInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the length of the array not always positive?

It is in your case. However, the problematic call doesn't use the array length but a random number:

```
generarAleatorio( generarAleatorio(mes.length) )
```

Here the inner `generarAleatorio(mes.length)` may return `0` in which case the outer `generarAleatorio(0)` fails.

How to fix the problem depends on what you want to do. Both of the following changes would make the error go away -- but the behavior of your program will be very different.

```
mes[generarAleatorio(generarAleatorio(mes.length)+1)]
```

```
mes[generarAleatorio(mes.length)]
```